# Issues with Date Range on Spotfire Visualization

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I'm trying to programmatically filter a SpotFire visualization based off a date column in my data table. More specifically I'm trying to filter the visualization so that it shows only the time period between the most recently completed month and the month before that (Month over month comparison). For example if it is currently June the visualization should show only April-May.

I've tried to use DateTime objects to accomplish this, but I am running into some problems.

```py
today = DateTime.Today
momEnd = today.AddDays(-today.Day)
momBeg = today.AddMonths(-2).AddDays(-today.Day+1)

for visual in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    if visual.Title == myVis.Title:
        newVis = visual.As[Visualization]()
        newVis.XAxis.Range = AxisRange(momBeg, momEnd)
```

This code does filter the visualization, but it shows only the month of January 2016 when it should show April-May of 2019.

Printing the newVis.XAxis.Range variable shows the following string:

```
    AxisRange[Low=4/1/2019 12:00:00 AM, High=5/31/2019 12:00:00 AM]
```

This should be correct, but as I mentioned I am not seeing the correct behavior from the visualization.

Any fix or alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm working with proprietary data, so I can't provide sample data. I actually found a workaround for this. Instead of using XAxis.Range I simply filtered the visualization data directly. Basically I replaced

```py
newVis.XAxis.Range = AxisRange(momBeg, momEnd)
```

with:

```py
newVis.Data.WhereClauseExpression = "[" + timeColumn + "] >= Date(Year(DateTimeNow()),Month(DateTimeNow())-2,1) AND [" + timeColumn + "] <= DateAdd(\"day\",-1,date(Year(DateTimeNow()),Month(DateTimeNow()),1))"
```

where timeColumn is the data column containing the date values

Comment: could you please provide some sample data? from what you show here this should be working properly. also check that there isn't some other filtering or data limiting expression being applied that might be overriding the AxisRange.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are doing this through IronPython. You could use data limiting directly on the visualization.

```
(DateDiff('month',
    Date(DatePart('year', [Timestamp]), DatePart('month', [Timestamp]), 1),
    DateTimeNow()) > 1 
And DateDiff('month',
    Date(DatePart('year', [Timestamp]), DatePart('month', [Timestamp]), 1),
    DateTimeNow()) < 3)
```

Comment: You could simply directly filter each visualization, but I need this to work for any given visualization. This code snippet is part of a larger script that aggregates data, does comparisons, and duplicates/filters visualizations based off those comparisons and some user input. This script needs to work on any visualization on any dashboard which is why I am doing the filters programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I should mention that I resolved my issue, and addressed the solution as an edit to my original question.